# How to manage ASP.NET Core web.config when using Visual Studio IIS debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

Visual Studio supports development-time IIS Support for ASP.NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0), e.g. I can debug a .NET 6 web app against local IIS from within Visual Studio.

In my particular case, I have set up a `launchSettings.json` file with my IIS settings, including environment variables for testing locally, like in the example:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost/WebApplication1",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

What this does is at runtime when debugging locally, Visual Studio creates a `web.config` file in the project directory. That's all good, makes sense, and local debugging works great.

I'm wrestling with how to manage the `web.config` beyond that. In the example above publishing as-is will keep the ENVIRONMENT set to "Development" unless I change something. I don't want my local environment variables from `launchSettings.json` to make it to the deployed build. I could make a `web.Release.config` transform and clear out the `<environmentVariables>` element.

But ideally I think I would have the build generate a new `web.config` each time, as it would do if I didn't have the existing `web.config` that was auto-generated from the debugger launch profiles.

What is the recommended way to deal with this, assuming that I just want the stock web.config behavior and don't actually have any embedded environment variable settings I want to include? Go with the transforms and remember to include that in any future projects?  Is there any way to keep the local IIS debugging settings in `launchSettings`, but have the project somehow know to ignore that `web.config` on Release build and create from new?

Comment: According to your description, do you want to ask how to save IIS startup settings on ASP.NET Core web.config?

Comment: I think I am looking for sort of the opposite. By default, there is no web.config in an ASP.NET Core project. By adding debugger IIS startup settings, a web.config file gets created. This is great for my local development, but I would like to have the project "ignore" the generated web.config on my eventual release build - I want to use the generated web.config for local development, but have the project behave as "default" when doing a release build. I could use a release transform, but that feels like I'm fighting against whatever automatically generates the web.config in the first place.